# if conditional using jquery that stops collapse('hide') function - Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a responsive dropdown on my webpage.  Works as intended on desktop/laptop browsers.  However, when you use a phone or ipad with a smaller screen, the nav gets hidden after I click a link that should present another dropdown menu.

Here's the js function. -

```
$('.navbar-collapse a').click(function(){
    $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
});
```

and the html -

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a href="#home"><img src="images/Logo-banner.jpg" height="auto" width="auto" /></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right text-uppercase">
                    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle ddown" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Services <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#computer-tablet-phone-service">Computer, Tablet &amp Phone Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#on-site-service">On Site Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#remote-service">Remote Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#managed-services">Managed Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#data">Data Backup Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#surveillance">Surveillance Systems</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#computer-sales">New &amp Used Computer Sales</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#custom-pcs">Custom Built Computers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#voip">VOIP Phones</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#web-design">Web Design &amp Hosting</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/upload/index.php">Shop Online</a></li>
                    <!--<li><a href="#pricing">About</a></li>-->
                    <li><a href="#download">Download</a></li>
                    <!--<li><a href="#download">Contact</a></li>-->
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

What I'm thinking I have to do is create a conditional in the js that will not execute the hide function if it is of a certain class.  I really don't have much experience with js though.  Here's what I tried.

```
$('.navbar-collapse a').click(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass("ddown")) {
        $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');}
});
```

Any tips? Suggestions? Solutions? Anybody see this before?

Comment: your function prevent the navbar collapse if ddown is present..... so that dont solve your problem??

Comment: Unfortunately that's not working for some reason.  Maybe I don't have the class in the right place, or bootstraps settings are overriding something and I need to add something to make it work correctly.

Comment: try use prevent default inside the if

Comment: @Vanojx1  That worked my friend.  Thank you for the solution.  My god was that ever giving me a headache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having the same problem with bootstrap responsive dropdowns auto-closing after being clicked inside parent nav-menu here is the solution.

Add a class to the link you would click on that would drop down the menu, name it whatever you want (i named mine "ddown):

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right text-uppercase">
                    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle ddown" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Services <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#computer-tablet-phone-service">Computer, Tablet &amp Phone Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#on-site-service">On Site Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#remote-service">Remote Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#managed-services">Managed Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#data">Data Backup Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#surveillance">Surveillance Systems</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#computer-sales">New &amp Used Computer Sales</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#custom-pcs">Custom Built Computers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#voip">VOIP Phones</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#web-design">Web Design &amp Hosting</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/upload/index.php">Shop Online</a></li>
```

Then add this if to your navbar function in your javascript:

```
$('.navbar-collapse a').click(function(){
if($(this).hasClass("ddown")) {
    event.preventDefault();}
    else {
        $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
    }
});
```

That's it, Good luck.